# Web services images set as background image for button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Want to set the Webservies image to button back ground images in tableview

```
{
"results": {

    "results": [
        {
            "id": "167",
            "image": "http: 20141115003645.png", //// set any images
            "exercise_name": "Cable Body Weight seated"
        }
    ]
},
"status": "OK"
}
```

"image" i getting the images i want to show that image as  button back ground...
how can i achieve this help me!!!!

Comment: show the full  Webservies  result

Comment: i show it want to set that "image" as a button back ground in tableview help me

Comment: Sorry anna.. now i correct it.. serves la vara image button back ground set pananum.. help me

Comment: sure me ma, 5 mins than panidallam unoda php url name ena

Comment: ithu static a ila dyanmic a means multiple image varumna ila intha oru image thana

Comment: response la pana mudiyatha anna...

Comment: dyanmic images varum

Comment: dyanmic images varum anna,, any doubt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 NSMutableArray *imagearray=[NSMutableArray new];  // this is your tableArray

    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options: kNilOptions error:nil];   // your json response started with Dictionary

    NSArray *imagekey=[[jsonDict objectForKey:@"results"]objectForKey:@"results"];

    for (NSDictionary *tmp in imagekey)
    {
        NSDictionary *tmpimagekey=[NSMutableDictionary new];

         [tmpimagekey setValue:[tmp objectForKey:@"image"] forKey:@"image"];

        [imagearray addObject:tmpimagekey];

    }
    [yourtableName reloadData];
```

in your `cell` method

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

// here cell process
```

NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"herpassyourURL/%@",[[imagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] objectForKey:@"image"]]]];
    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

```
[yourbuttonName setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:image] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[yourbuttonName addTarget:self action:@selector(imagebuttonclicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell.contentView addSubview:yourbuttonName];


       return cell;
}

-(void)imagebuttonclicked
{
// do ur stuff
}
```

Comment: only one mistake i did ,bz i  don't know your image server path, if i know i answered clearly,

Comment: if u need any assistance , i hope with u

Comment: Thanx u.. so much  ur mail id poe

Comment: karthik.saral@gmail.com(FB,Skype,twitter,gmail,SO)